# Error installing Windows SDK v6.1 with windowssdkver command: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, sdk

When installing Windows SDK v6.1, following the chromium instructions (http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows)

I run the following command:

```
windowssdkver -version:v6.1 -legacy
```

I get the following error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Version..ctor(String version)
   at WindowsSdkVer.Utility.GetInstalledProducts(String rootKey, String productVersionKey, String installationFolderKey)
   at WindowsSdkVer.VersionSelector.GetInstlledSdkVersions()
   at WindowsSdkVer.ConsoleSelectionManager.get_InstalledSdkVersions()
   at WindowsSdkVer.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution i find is to do this:

- Reboot first (just to be safe)
- Go into Regedit -> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A
- Rename the key 'ProductVersion' to '-ProductVersion'
- Run the windowssdkver command, it seems to work then
- Go back into regedit, and rename the key back to its original name.

Comment: If anyone's wondering why i answered my own question, i couldn't find anywhere on the Net with a good answer for this, other than a MSDN site that wouldn't allow replies other than from a MS PM who admitted they've got problems.